# overwrite existing xml value through java script

Tags: javascript, filewriter

This is my form .html code all value write in xml format through javascript

```
<form id='mrgv"+i+"'>
  <table class='propform'> 
    <tr><td colspan='2'><b>Visual Properties</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type='text' id='delimitDatanameVisual'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='delimitDatadescVisual'></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><b>Rule Engine Properties</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1. Id &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td> <input type='text' id='delimitDataidValue'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2. Phase No: &nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='delimitDataphaseNo'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3. KeyFields:</td><td><input type='text' id='delimitDatafileurl' /></td>
        <td><select id='delimitDataabs'>
              <option value='abs'>abs</option>
              <option value='ph'>ph</option></tr>
    <tr><td>4. OPR Flag: &nbsp;</td>
        <td><select id='delimitDataencoding'> 
              <option value='Inner'>Inner</option>
              <option value='LeftOuter'>LeftOuter</option>
              <option value='Duplicate'>Duplicate</option>
              <option value='RightOuter'>RightOuter</option>
            </select></font></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5. OutFlag:</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='outmv' /></td>
        <td><select id='delimitDataabs'> 
              <option value='abs'>abs</option>
              <option value='ph'>ph</option>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This is my javascript which write above form value to xml

```
function mrgv(i)
{              
  var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var file = object.OpenTextFile("D:\\vyas\\hello.grf",8,true,0);
  var mrgvform=document.getElementById("mrgv"+i);

  var idValue = mrgvform.delimitDataidValue.value;
  var phaseNo = mrgvform.delimitDataphaseNo.value;
  var keyfields=mrgvform.delimitDatafileurl.value;

  var oprflag =mrgvform.delimitDataencoding;
  var oprflagg = oprflag.options[oprflag.selectedIndex].text;

  var outflag =mrgvform.outmv.value;

  //file.WriteLine("<graph>");
  file.WriteLine("<Node" + " id=\"" + idValue +"\" "+ "" + "type=\"MERGE_V\" "+ " " + "Phase No=\""+ phaseNo +"\" "+ "  " + "keyfields=\"" + keyfields +"\" " + " " + "oprflag=\"" + oprflagg +"\" " + "" + "outflag=\"" + outflag +"\" " + " ></Node>" );

  //file.WriteLine("</graph>");
  file.Close();
}
```

My problem is: I want to redirect all value to xml. is already done.if again submit values from form than its append to next line but i want to overwrite that value on existing value.

Comment: I noticed that in your form html you are missing end tags for some selects and td's.
Could you also rephrase your question because it's not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: its already fine code just wordwrap it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the XML file to be overwritten with new values each time, rather than appended to like a log file. You are using an append method to write to the file, so it will not clear the existing contents.

```
// you should delete the `D:\\vyas\\hello.grf` file here so it
// is re-created as an empty file on the next line
var file = object.OpenTextFile("D:\\vyas\\hello.grf",8,true,0);
```

Comment: yes u r exactlly got my question now please help me to solveout this one. how to rewrite the value.